# Magnetic field outside a long cylinder with two different current densities

Tags: homework-and-exercises

The text of the problem goes as follows. In the entire space there exists current density:

$$\vec{j}(\rho )= j_{0}\left(\frac{\rho _{0}}{\rho }\right)^3\hat{\!\!\phi}$$

There also exists a cylindrical shell whose axis of symmetry coincides with the $z$-axis and has a radius $\rho_{0} $. On the surface of the cylinder flows a surface current:

$$\vec{j}= K_{0}\:\hat{\!\!\phi}$$

Find the constant $K_{0}$ so that magnitude is the same on the both sides of the cylinder, but its direction is opposite. Assume magnetic field approaches zero as distance approaches infinity.

In my attempt of solution I tried to use the superposition of two currents, but when I attempted to integrate the current that depends on the distance in the lower bound the integral when calculating Ampere's law diverges.

Also, how am I supposed to integrate the surface current on the surface of the cylinder when it is only an infinitesimal line? Do I integrate it as $K_{0}\, dz$ or do I have to take the distance from the axis into consideration as $\rho_{0}K_{0}\,dz$?

And, my last concern is the direction of the magnetic field, obviously inside the cylinder it would be in the $z$-axis direction, but I cannot deduce if the field outside will have any other component.

I honestly have a feeling that I am misinterpreting something completely, so any insight would be most welcome!